# Calculate non-standard auto-increment automatically

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

The table I am working with does not have a standard auto-increment field to use as a primary key, so I need to come up with a way to automatically calculate the value that should be used in the field.

My first thought was to create a trigger to happen `AFTER INSERT`, however, as far as I can tell, there's no easy way to reference the row that was just inserted. I could do something like

```
UPDATE `table` SET `reference_number` = (SELECT ....) WHERE `reference_number` IS NULL
```

but because `reference_number` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, it cannot be null. (Does that mean it would be an empty string `''`?)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why it does not have a standard auto-increment field to use as a primary key?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Because it was designed before I was on the project ;-)

Comment: Because it was designed by two separate teams of college students with zero previous database experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER mkuuid BEFORE INSERT ON SomeTable
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.primary_key = UUID_SHORT();
 END
```